# Proof by induction, logic

Tags: logic, induction, propositional-calculus

I'd like you to comment if my following proof by induction is correct ($\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}).$

**Thesis**: *Every formula constructed from variable $p$ and connectives $\land$, $\lor$, $\top$ (and brackets) is equivalent to either $p$ or $\top$.*

Let $\phi_n$ be formula with depth of $n$, constructed only from variable $p$ and connectives $\land$, $\lor$, $\top$ (and brackets).

Let $X = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : \phi_n \equiv p \lor \phi_n \equiv \top \}$

**Base case.**
For $n=0$ we have $\phi_0=p$ or $\phi_0=\top$, so obviously $\phi_0 \equiv p \lor \phi_0 \equiv \top$ and $0 \in X$.

**Inductive step.**
Let's assume $k \in X$, where $k < n$, i. e. $\phi_k \equiv p \lor \phi_k \equiv \top$ (this is inductive hypothesis). We will show that $n \in X$. Let's look at the cases for $\phi_n$:
1) $\phi_n = \phi_k \lor \phi'_{n-1-k}$. We know from our inductive hypothesis that $k \in X$ and $n-1-k \in X$, so we get four equivalent formulas $p \lor \top$, $p \lor p$, $\top \lor \top$ and $\top \lor p$. Obviously $p \lor \top \equiv \top \lor p \equiv \top \lor \top \equiv \top$ and $p \lor p \equiv p$.
2) $\phi_n = \phi_k \land \phi'_{n-1-k}$. We know from our inductive hypothesis that $k \in X$ and $n-1-k \in X$, so we get four equivalent formulas $p \land \top$, $p \land p$, $\top \land \top$ and $\top \land p$. Obviously $p \land \top \equiv \top \land p \equiv p \land p \equiv p$ and $\top \land \top \equiv \top$.
Therefore $n \in X$, so by mathematical induction, formula $\phi_n$ of depth $n  \geqslant 1$ constructed only from variable $p$ and connectives $\land$, $\lor$, $\top$ (and brackets) is equivalent to either $p$ or $\top$.

Comment: How do you define the modal depth?

Comment: I would use structural induction over the syntactical formation of formulas, rather than induction over the numbers, so you don't have to bother with any kind of numbers at all.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf of course typo, I meant $\phi_0$ and I define modal depth  in way described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_depth

Comment: @Bram28 I know that structural induction is more natural approach here, but I just wanted to know if casual induction is correct

Comment: But then the modal depth of $\phi_k\lor\phi_{n-k}$ is $\max\{k,n-k\}$ and not $n$. And by induction, the modal depths of all your formulas are $0$.

Comment: @teju14 Yes, that works too, and your proof looks fine to me!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Oh, of course, I thought it was something different. Let's define formula's depth as a number of its logical connectives (besides $\top$ and $\bot$)

Comment: Then in the inductive step it should rather be: 1) $\phi_n=\phi_k\lor\phi_{n-1-k}$ and similarly 2) $\phi_n=\phi_k\land\phi_{n-1-k}$.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Actually I corrected the proof and made it from $n=1$, that is formula with no logical connectives has a depth of $1$, with $n$ connectives has a depth of $n+1$ (not counting $\top$ and $\bot$)

Comment: I would leave it as it was before: the “depth” would be the total number of $\lor$ or $\land$ in the formula. So that the formulas with length $0$ are $p$ and $\top$ and every formula $\phi_n$ of depth $n\geq1$ can be uniquely written as $\phi_n=\phi_k\land\phi'_{n-1-k}$ or $\phi_n=\phi_k\lor\phi'_{n-1-k}$ with the depth of $\phi_k$ being $k$ with $0\leq k\leq n-1$ and the depth of $\phi'_{n-1-k}$ being $n-1-k$. When I say _uniquely,_ I'm understanding that $\land$ and $\lor$ are binary operators.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Okay, actually it seems more reasonable that $p$ or $\top$ has a depth of $0$. And right, It should be clear that these formulas can be different, so it should be $\phi'$ instead of $\phi$, thanks